# Semi-colon in set notation

Tags: probability-theory, elementary-set-theory, notation

In a math text, what does something like
$$
\{ (1,2,3,\dots, n); n\in \mathbb{N}\}
$$
mean?

More specifically, would it be $\{(1,2,3,\dots, n)\}$ *for a specific $n \in \mathbb{N}$*, or would it be $\{ (1), (1,2), (1,2,3) , \dots \}$. That is, would it apply *to all $n\in \mathbb{N}$*?

I ask because I guess I am confused on the use of $;$ in set notation versus $:$. Semi-colon is such that, so if the set was $\{ (1,2,3,\dots, n); n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ I believe it would apply for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Semicolon is for a specific $n$ perhaps though? I can't find much reference to this, although the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation#Formal_set_builder_notation_sets) says the semicolon serves to add an additional rule. That is, the semicolon (or comma) is like an "and".

Where I have encountered this notation? Rosenthal's introduction to probability theory.

Comment: It’s simply a variant of the colon notation. I’ve only very rarely seen it in the U.S., but it means the same thing.

Comment: Alright, Thank you very much.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott aka. a variant of the bar notation :)

Comment: I'm more used to the notation $\{(1,\ldots,n)\mid n\in \Bbb N\}$, but yes, it means the same thing.

Comment: Which part of the book?

Comment: @BCLC section 2.6 coin tossing. Pages 20 and 21 in my copy.

Comment: Rosenthal consistently uses $\{\ldots ; \ldots\}$ rather than $\{\ldots:\ldots\}$.  In fact, this notation appears in the joint paper we wrote with  Jason Wei (I hadn't noticed that before now!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\{(1,2,3,\dots,n) : n\in\mathbb N\} = \{ (1), (1,2), (1,2,3) , \dots \}
$$

Comment: I am marking this as the answer, but I am noting here in the comments a semi-colon is sometimes (although I guess very seldom) used in place of a colon, in the left hand side of that equation -- this was pointed out in the comments on my question. I mention this because my question was more about the semi-colon than the the colon, and the title may lead people here who want to know about the semi-colon.

Answer (score 1):

$$
'\{ (1,2,3,\dots, n); n\in \mathbb{N}\}'
$$

is the same thing as

$$
\{(1), (1,2),\ldots \}
$$

---

Check out:

---

[image]

---

I don't think we have $\Omega = \{(0,0,...) \cup (1,1,...)\}$

Comment: I am reading that page as saying that $\Omega = \{(0,0,\dots), (1,0,\dots) , (0,1,\dots),\dots \}$, which I think makes sense since the sample space is all possible outcomes, of which there are (countably) infinitely many.

Comment: @majmun Right so we do have $\{(1), (1,2),...\}$

Comment: Yes, My apologies; you are correct.