# Reading Set Expression as it is Spoken

Tags: graph-theory

I am reading a paper pertaining to TSP and came with the following paragraph:

[image: t]

I want to ask how to read the union expression in the above paragraph, why are there two $P_k$? So inorder to read it out does it say

> All Union of $P_k$ element of $L$, we form the set of vertices?

If that is so how to intrepret the two $P_k$'s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each $P_k$ is a subset of nodes, and $V$ (not defined in the quoted paragraph) is presumably the full node set in the original graph. The equality says that the nodes in the paths $P_k$ together cover all nodes in $V$.  The $P_k$ in the subscript is an index.  It might have been less confusing to write the union as $\cup_{k=1}^{|\mathcal{L}|} P_k$.

Comment: Your union expression makes more sense. So in short does the index $P_k$ in the subscript imply that we do $k=1$ to |$L$|?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, if by mod you mean cardinality.

Comment: I have one small question as well, does this expression with semicolon $$a_i ≤v_i ≤b_i ∀i∈P_k;∀P_k$$ here mean for all $(P_1),(P_1,P_2),..(..,P_k)$? as described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1600241/semi-colon-in-set-notation) or it simply mean "for all $P_k$"?

Comment: No, the semicolon ends one set of conditions over nodes in a path. The next set of conditions is over pairs of paths.

Comment: Perfect. Makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I would read it as 'The union over all elements $P_{k}$ in $L$'.